# Clicking the submitButton of shiny tutorial using selenium

Tags: python, r, selenium, shiny

I am trying to setup R shiny and the Selenium automation web tool for testing. I try to use selenium the submit button of the Shiny tutorial example but it is not working. The button becomes selected but the textOutput does not change to the new textInput value. Below I paste the server.R, UI.R and python selenium comands. Thank you for any hint.

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$n))
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    paste("Input text is:", input$text)
  })
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("submitButton example"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      sliderInput("n", "N:", min = 10, max = 1000, value = 200,
                  step = 10),
      textInput("text", "Text:", "text here"),
      HTML("<button id='submitid' type='submit'>Submit</button>")
    )),
    column(6,
           plotOutput("plot1", width = 400, height = 300),
           verbatimTextOutput("text")
    )
  )
))
```

My python selenium commands:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8010/")

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('text').setAttribute('value', 'aaa')");
submit=driver.find_element_by_id("submitid")
submit.click()
```